# Sent email not using UTF-8

Tags: java, html, email, utf-8, thymeleaf

I have been developing a web application using Thymeleaf and one of the functions in that application is to the send emails to users(test users in this case) once certain changes have been done in the application. However when the emails are received by users the message gets garbled because it doesn't use UTF-8 and so far I haven't managed to figure out where the problem is. I was wondering if some fresh eyes might see what I'm missing?

P.S. The IDE I'm currently using is IntelliJ.

Thanks in advance!

Code

```
import email.MailSender;

MailSender sender = MailSenderProvider.getMailSender();

sender.sendMail(studentEmail,"Du har fått en ny handledare","Hej! "+name+ " <br>" + "Du har fått en ny handledare "+ " <br>"+
                        "logga in på: "+  "<a href='vfusocionom.hig.se'>" + "Vfusocionom.hig.se " + "</a>"+ "<br>"  +"för att se extra detaljer"  );
```

[image: The picture in question]

Comment: Welcome to the 1990’s. You should look into MIME encoding as It solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the total opposite of your claims seems to be the problem and solution.

Instantly 3 solutions come to mind:

1. The classic solution. Use the antique HTML escaping codes to encode your special characters, like `&uuml;` für `ü` and `&szlig;` for `ß` etc. You can also use html codes. The english pound currency symbol `£` for example can be written as `&pound;` or `&#163;` (dec) or `&#x00A3;` (hex), see https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_latin1_supplement.asp for examples.
2. As you are already using HTML, you could define the language in the `<!DOCTYPE>` and even specify the correct encoding in `<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` if it really IS UTF-8.
3. Maybe it is not even the UTF-8 that poses the problem, but your IDE that saves the file with a different encoding. Make sure the .java source code file is actually UTF-8-encoded. Open it with notepad++ for example, and manually set the encoding via menu to UTF-8